# Insert the content of an HTML file using JavaScript

Tags: ajax, dojo, cross-domain

I need to display some data(some text message) from a URL**(an HTML file)** which is in a different domain. I thought about using an `iFrame` to display the markup. Now the problem could be
if that site is down, then I wil see `404` error in that `iFrame`. i want to avoid that. I thought about using `dojo` to make an AJAX call to that URL to get the response, use `innerHTML`
to insert the response to the `DOM`. This is all what I need. But due to cross domain AJAX issues, I don't think it is possible. We are using dojo in our application. I searched
in Google to find a good implementation of Cross Domain scripting using Dojo. All I found is stuffs like `JSONP`. I don't want to make the remote domain return a `JSONP`. It is 
just an HTML file and that file contains the markup that I need to print to the console. Can someone suggest a good way to do this.

Comment: loading cross domain data without JSONP is not possible

Comment: only possible if u fetch that content on your server and do a ajax on your server to fetch this content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly as was already mentioned by Nakul in the comments, the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) does not allow for cross-domain XHR requests (at least in a cross-browser way).

The workarounds involve either cooperation from the cross-domain site (JSONP, CORS, various iframe communication tricks) or setting up a proxy in your own server so that all "cross-domain" go through your own domain first.